# Extract variable text from string using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

So, I think I'm close, but can't quite get this to work.

I'm pulling in information from another site using curl, this is stored in $source.

I have stripped $source of html tags etc, so it comes across almost as plain text.

I want to extract a persons name, which is variable, from $source.  From the output I can isolate some unique code with will always surround the name and nothing else, but can seem to extract the name.

If I echo $source, it will contain:

*div div div section idname div classcontainer header classsection header h3 John Smith h3 h4 classtext center*

I'm looking to pull out John Smith and store it as $name

This is what I have, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
// Seek out the persons name
$a=preg_match('/div div div section idname div classcontainer header classsection header h3(\w+)h3 h4 classtext center/',$source,$matches);
$Name = $matches[1];
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How variable is it?  why wouldn't you just get what's in between `h3  h3`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Well it's a persons name so generally between 2 and 4 words.  $source contains many h3 elements, the additional text before and after is to enable the correct portion of $source to be targeted.

Answer (score 0):

This will output John Smith if the name contains a first name and last name with a space in between.

You can try regexes in JS then stick the pattern in your PHP code.

This pattern just looks for the h3 delimiters, and extracts anything in between in a non-greedy way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to do a search for word characters in a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "div div div section idname div classcontainer header classsection header h3 John Smith h3 h4 classtext center"; 
    var patt1 = "/div div div section idname div classcontainer header classsection header h3 (.*?) h3 h4 classtext center/";
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[1];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as it's a persons name, it won't always follow the Name Name pattern, there could be more than just first and last.  Also there are multiple h3 elements in $source, I targeted the unique sting to ensure a single result.

Comment: Try this expression: `div div div section idname div classcontainer header classsection header h3 (.*?) h3 h4 classtext center`

Comment: Why do you give a javascript solution to a PHP question ?

Comment: Because the expression is valid in PHP as well as JS.  You can quickly experiment with live regex testing tools, or with a web page, then plug the working regex to your PHP code.

Comment: Couldn't get this solution to work either, but thanks for the effort.  Ended up with a workaround.  Replaced all spaces with "xzzx" (random string) using str_replace, then used my original code (with xzzx in place of the spaces) which allowed me to store "JohnxzzxSmith" as $Name, then reversed the str_replace to replace all "xzzx" with spaces, resulting in $Name equaling "John Smith".  Very messy workaround, but it'll hold until I figure it out properly.